# v4l2 loopback working fine with openCV but weird output on OBS

Tags: opencv, v4l2loopback

I'm as CS student and i'm trying to make a project where I output my webcam video flow but as an ascii art.

In order to do so, I get the image from v4l2. then i use OpenCV to decode the image (i wasn't able to find an easier way to do so)

Then i get the data from my openCV mat and, in a new buffer, create an ascii art from my image.
after that i send data from my buffer in v4l2 but when i use the v4l2 loopback input on obs the output is realy weird (see image)

I've tried to output the image in a new mat using opencv and the image output correctly. i really don't understand what happen neither why. Also i've tried to use discord instead of OBS the output is completely black ...

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks by advance.

(all my code is available through github, i'm not sure if i should post it since this is not stack overflow. if ever you need it just let me know i'll add a link)

Expected Output (got from OpenCV):
[image: Expected Output]

OBS Output :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> In order to do so, I get the image from v4l2. then i use OpenCV to decode the image (i wasn't able to find an easier way to do so)

You can use [`libcaca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libcaca)

> libcaca is a software library that converts images into colored ASCII art. It includes the library itself, and several programs including cacaview, an image viewer that works inside a terminal emulator, and img2txt, which can convert an image to other text-based format.

For example, if your webcam is `/dev/video1` this command will show a live feed of it, with ASCII art:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video1 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f caca -
```

Their [home page](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) has more information on the library and the parameters you can set.

Comment: That can be an idea but I want to do it by myself without using other lib. The only reason why I use openCV is because I was lazy decoding the image from V4L2 but in the future I'm aiming to remove it

Comment: You can maybe use ffmpeg+libcaca anyway to check if the problem is yours or somehow OBS's (configuration for example) and further narrow down then problem.

Comment: Didn't thought about that idea. Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer is useful you should click on the number to the left, it it solves your issue (this is not the case, but for the future), then mark it as solved.

Comment: Yeah i know how it work i'm used to SO ^^
I did not tried it yet i'm first waiting to try it before upvoting (i'm not even sure i can upvote since i'm a new contibutor here) 
Thanks for explainning tho